# Reset all selectInput to default values in a hierarchy structure

Tags: r, shiny, reset, selectinput

I have a two-step hierarchy of selectInputs. I want a solution that whenever I select a new "sports" the current values of the selectInput are reset to the default value 0. Right now my code only reset the values of the newly selected chosen sport. Not the old values of the previous "sport" of choice, I want both to be reset if possible. I thought if I chose all inputs to be updated in observeEvent it would fix that. But it appears it doesn't. Also I don't mind that if a sport has not been chosen that the input value is empty.

I have tried to look for other answers like this one:
[Shiny R: Reset other input values when selectInput value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884084/shiny-r-reset-other-input-values-when-selectinput-value-changes) .
But I am not sure this is the solution I want. Here is an example I wrote that explains it.

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Menu"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Chose Sport"),
      
      selectInput("case", 
                  label = "Sport",
                  choices = list(
                   "Hockey",
                   "Football",
                   "Basketball"
                    )),
      
      uiOutput("mychoices")
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("printvalues")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  gender <- selectInput(     inputId="select_gender", 
                             label = "Gender",
                             choices = list("Male" = 1, "Female" = 2, "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  
  hockey <- selectInput(     inputId="select_hockey", 
                             label = "Hockey",
                             choices = list("A" = 1, 
                                            "B" = 2,
                                            "C" = 3,
                                            "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  
  football <- selectInput(   inputId="select_football", 
                             label = "Football",
                             choices = list("D" = 1, 
                                            "E" = 2,
                                            "F" = 3,
                                            "G" = 5,
                                            "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  
  basketball <- selectInput(   inputId="select_basketball", 
                             label = "Basketball",
                             choices = list("H" = 1, 
                                            "I" = 2,
                                            "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  
  output$mychoices <- renderUI({
    switch(input$case,
           "Hockey" = list(gender, hockey), 
           "Football" =  list(gender, football),
           "Basketball" =  list(gender, basketball),
    )
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$case, {
    # Reset all the input values to their default values
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_gender", selected = 0)
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_hockey", selected = 0)
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_football", selected = 0)
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_basketball", selected = 0)
  })
  
  
  output$printvalues = renderUI({
    
    print_values <- c(input$select_gender, input$select_hockey, input$select_football, input$select_basketball)
    
    print(print_values)
    
    row.1 = paste("Gender:", input$select_gender)
    row.2 = paste("Hockey:", input$select_hockey)
    row.3 = paste("Football:", input$select_football)
    row.4 = paste("Basketball:", input$select_basketball)
    HTML(paste(row.1, row.2, row.3, row.4,sep="<br>"))
    
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That is because `output$mychoices` defines only gender and one sport in the `renderUI`.  Define all sports (selectInputs) in `ui`, and then you should be able to reset.

Comment: I don't want the other sports to be shown in my `output$mychoices `. But if I understand you right, the reason why not all values are reseted is because of the `switch` function has only gender and one sports only specified per choice? Hmm how do I get around that?

Comment: Perhaps you can try `conditionalPanel()` or `hide/show` from shinyjs package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `shinyjs` package.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Menu"),
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Chose Sport"),
      
      selectInput("case", 
                  label = "Sport",
                  choices = list(
                    "Hockey",
                    "Football",
                    "Basketball"
                  )),
      uiOutput("g"),
      uiOutput("H"),
      uiOutput("F"),
      uiOutput("B")
      #uiOutput("mychoices")
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("printvalues")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  # gender <- selectInput(     inputId="select_gender", 
  #                            label = "Gender",
  #                            choices = list("Male" = 1, "Female" = 2, "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  
  hockey <- selectInput(     inputId="select_hockey", 
                             label = "Hockey",
                             choices = list("A" = 1, 
                                            "B" = 2,
                                            "C" = 3,
                                            "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  
  football <- selectInput(   inputId="select_football", 
                             label = "Football",
                             choices = list("D" = 1, 
                                            "E" = 2,
                                            "F" = 3,
                                            "G" = 5,
                                            "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  
  basketball <- selectInput(   inputId="select_basketball", 
                               label = "Basketball",
                               choices = list("H" = 1, 
                                              "I" = 2,
                                              "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  
  output$g <- renderUI({
    selectInput(     inputId="select_gender", 
                     label = "Gender",
                     choices = list("Male" = 1, "Female" = 2, "-" = 0), selected = 0)
  })
  
  output$H <- renderUI({
    hockey
  })
  output$F <- renderUI({
    football
  })
  output$B <- renderUI({
    basketball
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$case, {
    # Reset all the input values to their default values
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_gender", selected = 0)
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_hockey", selected = 0)
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_football", selected = 0)
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_basketball", selected = 0)
    if(input$case == "Hockey") {
      shinyjs::show("H")
      shinyjs::hide("F")
      shinyjs::hide("B")
    } else if (input$case == "Football") {
      shinyjs::show("F")
      shinyjs::hide("H")
      shinyjs::hide("B")
    } else if (input$case == "Basketball") {
      shinyjs::show("B")
      shinyjs::hide("F")
      shinyjs::hide("H")
    } 
    
  })
  
  
  output$printvalues = renderUI({
    
    print_values <- c(input$select_gender, input$select_hockey, input$select_football, input$select_basketball)
    
    print(print_values)
    
    row.1 = paste("Gender:", input$select_gender)
    row.2 = paste("Hockey:", input$select_hockey)
    row.3 = paste("Football:", input$select_football)
    row.4 = paste("Basketball:", input$select_basketball)
    HTML(paste(row.1, row.2, row.3, row.4,sep="<br>"))
    
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```